# Unable to deploy JavaFX 2 jar from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jar, javafx

I have an Eclipse project which uses JavaFX 2. The FXML files are generated using Scene Builder. My goal is to create a runnable Jar. No matter in which way I tried, I always get a JavAFX Launcher Error "Exception while running Application"/ when running the jar file. The stack trace is below.

The same results if I use the JavaFX ant tasks or the javafxpackager utility.

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.javafx.main.Main.launchApp(Main.java:642)
    at com.javafx.main.Main.main(Main.java:805)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at     com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:403)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:47)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:115)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at controllers.Main.start(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$5.run(LauncherImpl.java:319)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$5.run(PlatformImpl.java:206)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(PlatformImpl.java:173)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:29)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:73)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was the relative paths in the code. When referring to images or FXML files, I would use a relative path. This worked fine when running directly from Eclipse, but did not work as a runnable jar. Changing the paths to absolute fixed the problem.

EDIT: For anyone stumbling upon this error and using Scene Builder to make the FXML files, note that I had to edit the generated FXML files from Scene Builder using a text editor to convert the relative paths to absolute.

Comment: Wow, that error message was really unhelpful in determining the root cause of the problem - nice work in tracking it down.  You can mark your self answer as correct.

Comment: How would you use an absolute path if you're making a jar? Could you post an example of how the relative path was and how the absolute path is?

Answer (score 1):

If you can use maven , then follow  [this tutorial](http://www.zenjava.com/2012/11/24/from-zero-to-javafx-in-5-minutes/) to create executable jar,exe .. etc.

> Maven Plugin for JavaFX: Using this plugin it’s much, much easier to
>   get up and running quickly and to build complicated distribution
>   bundles (such as executable JAR files, native installers and webstart
>   bundles).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but converting the eclipse project to Maven is time consuming. I've found the issue and posted it in the answers.